# How do disable Transfer-Encoding in Tomcat 6

Tags: http-headers, tomcat6, chunked-encoding

I have a web application running on Tomcat 6.0.29 server and JDK 1.6.

When I send the response to the client, Tomcat sends

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

in the headers when the response size is > 8KB. For responses < 8KB, it sends

```
Content-Length :
```

I understand that [Chunked encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) is the preferred way to handle bulk responses, however our clients do not want to change their code (as it is distributed all across the servers).

How can I disable Chunked encoding in Tomcat?

I could Disable HTTP/1.1 in Tomcat and enable HTTP/1.0 (not sure how I can do this)

I tried the following with no success:

1. In Connector tag in `server.xml`, I set `bufferSize =" 65536"`

   ```
   Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
          connectionTimeout="20000"
          bufferSize="65536" socketBuffer="65536"
          redirectPort="8443" /&gt;
   ```
2. Using NIOConnector in server.xml with following configuration:

   ```
   <Connector port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
          connectionTimeout="20000"
          socket.directBuffer="false"
          socket.rxBufSize="25188"
          socket.txBufSize="43800"
          socket.appReadBufSize="32768"
          socket.appWriteBufSize="32768"
          socket.bufferPool="500"
          socket.bufferPoolSize="100000000"
          socket.processorCache="500"
          socket.keyCache="500"
          socket.eventCache="500"
          socket.tcpNoDelay="false"
          socket.soKeepAlive="true"
          socket.soTimeout="5000"
          redirectPort="8443" />
   ```

Answer (score 8):

The only way I could get it working is by setting the BufferSize on response.

`response.setBufferSize()` sets the `Content-Length` header of the response size. Once the response size goes beyond the bufferSize it would fallback to `Transfer-Encoding: Chunked`. 
The buffer size should be set to an appropriate value. Setting it to a higher value would buffer all of the response in memory before flushing it. So the value should be set to an optimistic size.

Few of my clients are depending on `Content-Length` response header. I have to set this for backward compatibility. By default Tomcat buffer size is set to 8K (I think for Weblogic/Websphere this is 32K bytes).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, to disable chunked output in Tomcat you must supply a content length header in your servlet.

Comment: I don't want to set the Content-Length header programmatically. I expected either "bufferSize" or "socketBuffer" to do the magic. None of them work.

Comment: I'm fairly sure its the only way to get it working with tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a [Connection: close] header to the response prevents Tomcat from adding the [Transfer-Encoding: chunked] header.