# Disable chunking per request

Tags: flash, web-services, servlets, glassfish, chunked-encoding

I have a web service backed by a Java Servlet. The service is used by an older version of Flash. We discovered through some pain that in this version of Flash, `URLLoader` won't work with chunked responses. Any chunked response is never received from the server.

I am using Glassfish to host the Servlet. I know how to disable chunking for the entire server, but that seems like a bad idea (is it?).

Is there a standard way to disable chunking per request? I tried calling `ServletResponse.setBufferSize(SOME_LARGE_VALUE)` but surprising this did not affect the server's decision to use chunking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do disable Transfer-Encoding in Tomcat 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299432/how-do-disable-transfer-encoding-in-tomcat-6)

Answer (score 2):

From the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) of `HttpServlet#doGet()`:

> ...
>
> Where possible, set the `Content-Length` header (with the `ServletResponse.setContentLength(int)` method), to allow the servlet container to use a persistent connection to return its response to the client, improving performance. The content length is automatically set if the entire response fits inside the response buffer.
>
> When using HTTP 1.1 chunked encoding (which means that the response has a `Transfer-Encoding` header), do not set the `Content-Length` header.
>
> ...

So, if you set the response content length beforehand, then it won't be sent in chunked encoding.

```
response.setContentLength(contentLength);
// ...
```

---

**Update**: You also need to make sure that the servlet isn't in turn been called by `<jsp:include>` or `RequestDispatcher#include()`. See also [its javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29):

> ...
>
> The `ServletResponse` object has its path elements and parameters remain unchanged from the caller's. The included servlet cannot change the response status code or set headers; any attempt to make a change is ignored.
>
> ...

Comment: that makes sense, but it doesn't work on glassfish. the server still chunks even when the content length is set.

Comment: What Glassfish version? Are you certain that the header is set *before* any content is written? Do you see the header in the client side? Are you sure that you aren't setting the header in the resource which is been called by `<jsp:include>` or `RequestDispatcher#include()` (that would namely be totally ignored, see also [its javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29)).

Comment: GF 3.1; the header does not show, i still see "chunked"; no i'm not writing any content before setting the header

Comment: I'd bet that there's somewhere a bogus `HttpServletResponseWrapper` implementation in the request-response chain which is preventing that. Put a breakpoint on `setContentLength()` and track from it on.